# find the occurence of all words in a string from an array using php

Tags: php, arrays, string, file

$input='mymyntralove.com'
and i have one array
$array=array('my','myntra','love','myntralove');
and my expected output is:
my
myntra
love
.com

```
<?php
$mystring = 'cheapestbricks.com.au';
$findmes   = ['cheapest','bricks'];

$array = explode("\n", file_get_contents('test.txt'));


foreach($array as $findme) {

    $pos = strpos($mystring, trim($findme));
    if ($pos === false) {
        //echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
    } else {
        echo $findme.'<br/>';
    }
}
```

i read words from a text file and made one array and did this,but not getting correctly.anybody knows please help

Comment: Could you post an example line from your `test.txt` file?